# Рекурсивный перебор

Tags: c++, рекурсия

Подскажите или скорее научите пользоваться рекурсией для перебора вариантов.

> Например: есть строка `AB`, перебрать все варианты из этих символов:
>   `AB,BA`;

Comment: Комбинаторика, возможное количество перестановок без повторений.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

классическое решение

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

void permutations(std::string s, int pos = 0)
{
    if (pos >= s.size())
    {
        std::cout << s << '\n';
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = pos; i < s.size(); ++i)
        {
            std::swap(s[i], s[pos]);
            permutations(s, pos + 1);
            std::swap(s[i], s[pos]);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    permutations("ABCD");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Есть строка длиной N? Считаем,что мы знаем, как получить все перестановки для N-1.
Получаем. И в каждой вставляем N-ю букву во все возможные места...

Например:

```
void out(const string& buf, int num = 0, string s = "")
{
    if (num == buf.length())  // Полная строка, выводим...
    {
        cout << s << '\n';
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= s.length(); ++i)  // во все места более короткой строки
    {                                     
        string p = s;
        p.insert(i,1,buf[num]);           // вставляем очередной символ
        out(buf,num+1,p);                 // и вызываем рекурсивно...
    }
}

int main()
{
    out("ABCD");
}
```

Comment: а зачем? next_permutation не проще?

Comment: @pavel Задача у человека как стоит? Использовать **рекурсию** для перебора вариантов. Не просто получить перестановки, а посмотреть, как это делается **рекурсивно**. Соответственно вопросу - ответ.